# How to hide section tag element on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a one page html5 website where each page/section is in a section id = "name"

How would i hide one of these sections for example the "Place and Order" section if the website was being viewed on a mobile device?

The website is here - http://mk18.web44.net/

If its possible , I would also like to hide the menu option for that perticular page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a media query for mobile devices.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    element {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `element` is whatever you are trying to hide. If the id is name, you would replace `element` with `#name`.

Answer (score 0):

Reference the IDs for the sections you want to hide in a media query. To hide the "about" section on screens that are up to 600px wide:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #about {
    display: none;
  }
}
```